# how to add popup window in asp.net web form

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I want to add a popup window which is a child window of my main asp.NET form. This window accepts the information through drop down list selected by the user. When this window is opened the focus will go to this window and main window will disable.

Comment: just to confirm is this web?

Answer (score 2):

Use showModalDialog for opening the popup window.

```
window.showModalDialog("childpage.aspx", "", "center:yes;resizable:no;dialogHeight:480px;dialogWidth:750px;");
```

This will make parent page disabled in IE.

Comment: Wow, I'm not convinced that this approach is the best (I don't like that there's no feedback when you try to click the background window), but +1 anyway because I never knew about this command. Works great in current Firefox too, oddly.